# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate() blocking socket.io requests?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I'm not sure if there is something I don't understand or there's some kind of error, but I just can't figure this one out. Basically once in a while, I send a request from my server to an API to get some information back and then save it to my database, but whenever the data is being saved, socket.io requests get blocked and only when all of the data has been updated is when the other requests come through in a bunch. I know that they are getting blocked because I tried sending a chat message every 100ms while the data was being updated and the messages all came through ONLY when the last piece of the information from the API got saved and not one got through while it was being saved. How can I make it that it doesn't block other requests?

Here's an example of the console output when I was testing it out:

```
...
New chat message received
New chat message received
New chat message received
New chat message received
UPDATING 1455 ITEMS
UPDATED ALL PRICES, TOOK 3592
New chat message received
New chat message received
New chat message received
New chat message received
...
```

code:

```
request('url')), (err, response, body) => {
        let items = JSON.parse(body);
        let startTime = new Date().getTime();
        console.log(`UPDATING ${items.prices.length} ITEMS`);

        for (let i = 0; i < items.prices.length; i++) {
            const item = items.prices[i];

            Prices.findOneAndUpdate({item: item.name}, {$set: {price: item.price, last_update: Date.now()}}, (err, res) => {
                if(!res){
                    newPrice = new Prices({
                        item: item.name,
                        price: item.price
                    });

                    newPrice.save((err, saved) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    })
                }

                if(i == items.prices.length - 1){
                    console.log(`UPDATED ALL PRICES, TOOK ${new Date().getTime() - startTime}`);                    
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Not sure if this will help with anything, but here's the code that handles receiving messages:

```
socket.on('sendMessage', (data) => {
    User.findOne({id: socket.request.user.id}, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        //Check if the user is muted and if not, proceed
        if(user.mutedUntil < Date.now()){
            User.findOneAndUpdate({id: socket.request.user.id}, {$set: {lastMessageDate: Date.now()}}, (err, dbUser) => {
                if (err) throw err;

                let parsed = ParseMessage(data.message);                     

                if(parsed.command === 'none'){
                    SendMessage(dbUser, socket, data);
                }else{
                    commandData = {parsed: parsed, socket: socket}
                    ExecuteChatCommand(commandData);
                }
            });
        }else{
            socket.emit('serverMessage', {
                type: 'error',
                title: 'You\'re muted',
                message: 'You are muted and can\'t chat until ' + user.mutedUntil
            });
            console.log('Muted user tried chatting');
        }
    });       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is doing the blocking since it is a synchronous operation.

You should consider using **Promises** instead. Rather than the `for` loop use `Promise.map or Promise.all` in [BlueBird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) or [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in ES6 to achieve the same but in an async way.

For your queries you can use mongoose [.exec()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/promises.html) to convert them to full-fledged promises.

**Note**: You are trying to find & update `1455` times in that for loop ... Maybe look into [Promise.mapSeries](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.mapseries.html) in Bluebird so that the Promises are not all sent at the same time to Mongo but in serial fashion

Comment: Tried using `Promise.map` and at first it didn't make any difference, but when looking into it more, I found out about the `concurrency` option and when I set it to `1` it seems like the problem got solved and while updating my database other requests were not blocked. Thanks for the help!